# difference between ninesky and ninesky cn

Tags: applications, google-play-store, browser

Ninesky is a browser for android. What is the difference between [Ninesky](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ninesky-browser/com.ninesky.browser) and [Ninesky CN](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ninesky-browser-cn/com.ninesky.browsercn)?

Comment: I would guess the latter is a special version for China.  It doesn't mention the links to US news sites like the main version, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots of the CN version are all in Chinese, also the language code for Chinese Simplified is "CN".